# What is the purpose of static getInstance method in Enum Singleton?

Tags: java, enums, singleton

I was going through Singleton implementation using Enum and noticed static get instance method:

```
enum EnumSingleton {

INSTANCE("Initial class info"); 

private String info;

private EnumSingleton(String info) {
    this.info = info;
}

public static EnumSingleton getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
}


public String getInfo(){
    return this.info;
}

}
```

Since, Enum is by default public, I can do the following :

```
public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EnumSingleton es = EnumSingleton.getInstance();
    System.out.println(es.getInfo());
    
    EnumSingleton es1 = EnumSingleton.INSTANCE;
    System.out.println(es1.getInfo());
}
}
```

output of above main method is both sops print :

```
Initial class info                                                                                                                                                            
Initial class info
```

So what is the use case of public static EnumSingleton getInstance() ?

Comment: Why using Enum in combination with Singleton? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: There are multiple ways to implement a singleton and Singleton created with Enum are pretty straight forward. They provide safegaurd from Reflection, serialization and it is Thread safe. Here's an interesting article : https://www.baeldung.com/java-singleton

Answer (score -1):

Like described here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-singleton

there are some ways to implement Singleton: like regular class and like enum.

To use our ClassSingleton, we simply need to get the instance statically:

```
ClassSingleton classSingleton1 = ClassSingleton.getInstance();

System.out.println(classSingleton1.getInfo()); //Initial class info

ClassSingleton classSingleton2 = ClassSingleton.getInstance();
classSingleton2.setInfo("New class info");

System.out.println(classSingleton1.getInfo()); //New class info
System.out.println(classSingleton2.getInfo()); //New class info
```

As for the EnumSingleton, we can use it like any other Java Enum:

```
EnumSingleton enumSingleton1 = EnumSingleton.INSTANCE.getInstance();

System.out.println(enumSingleton1.getInfo()); //Initial enum info

EnumSingleton enumSingleton2 = EnumSingleton.INSTANCE.getInstance();
enumSingleton2.setInfo("New enum info");

System.out.println(enumSingleton1.getInfo()); // New enum info
System.out.println(enumSingleton2.getInfo()); // New enum info
```